# Getting .Net run to continue to next task in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to add a run task using the .Net Core task but after it shows that the app is up on a localhost, it can't move onto the next task. I believe it doesn't move onto the next task because the .Net task never ends. I want the task to run so that it is up on the localhost and then move onto the next task to test it. here's my pipeline

```yaml
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

resources:
 repositories:
   - repository: e2ecypress
     type: git
     name: devopsapp/e2ecypress

jobs:
  - job: build_unit_tests
    displayName: '.Net Build & Unit Test'

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'run'
        projects: '*/*.csproj'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume DotNetCoreCLI@2 just calls "dotnet run". If your program is a *console* program that "never ends", then I would indeed expect your pipeline to block there.

To start your program without blocking, I think that instead of using DotNetCoreCLI@2, you need to insert a "- script" that calls the Windows "start" command to directly call "dotnet run".